# Can I close my account on just this Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support

I would like to close my account, but only on the Stack Overflow. The others do at least allow me to contribute.

Exactly how many millions of views you must bring to this website before you are allowed to ask a question on your Python web scraper is unclear to me. If it is possible to have all your contributions deleted from just one Stack Exchange site and have the others left unaffected, I would like to do that, please.

Comment: [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/165261)

Comment: This, however, sounds like you want to delete your account for the *wrong* reasons, if I am honest. Deleting your account because you are question banned (which appears to be implied in the above) won't make things better; if you ever sign back up you will have an even *harder* time getting out of that ban, as you won't be able to edit and improve your prior content, and your account is likely to have limitations imposed on it immediately.

Comment: *"The others do at least allow me to contribute"* - for now. The same site mechanics apply there. If you don't acknowledge that you had a part to play in how your account ended up on Stack Overflow, it is likely to repeat at some point on another site.

Comment: "Exactly how many millions of views you must bring to this website before you are allowed to ask a question on your python webscraper is unclear to me." The answer is zero. If you were question-banned, it has nothing to do with failing to improve site traffic. (If anything, views occasionally get attracted by *unusually bad* questions.) If you were not question-banned, then you were not actually "disallowed" from asking a question; you were simply being told that **the question** was unsuitable for the site. In which case, it **doesn't matter** who's asking.

Answer (score 18):

> I would like to close my account but only on the StackOverflow SE.

You cannot close an account. However, you can *delete* it. To do so, start here: [How do I delete my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

> The others do at least allow me to contribute.

Stack Overflow also allowed you to contribute. In fact, you contributed 15 questions to Stack Overflow. That seems like a relatively large number. Why do you say that you weren't allowed to contribute?

I assume you mean that you aren't currently allowed to contribute, which is true, because you've hit [a rate limit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), due to having posted a large number of low-quality questions.

[Other Stack Exchange sites have this, too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142). So, Stack Overflow is no different in this regard. Blaming Stack Overflow isn't really fair, and certainly is inconsistent with the facts.

> Exactly how many millions of views you must bring to this website before you are allowed to ask a question on your python webscraper is unclear to me.

None. The number of views you bring to this website is completely irrelevant by all metrics. It certainly doesn't have any effect on whether you are allowed to post new questions.

> If it possible to have all your contributions deleted from just one SE and have the others left unaffected I would like to do that please.

No, this is not possible. Your contributions are not deleted. However, they will be *anonymized* (i.e., your name will be removed) when you delete your account on this site.

Comment: "That seems like a relatively large number." I did statistics on this once (or at least, figured out a SEDE query and downloaded a spreadsheet). Only about a quarter of users have asked **any** questions. The mean number of questions asked is less than two. Of course, there is a very long tail, with some users who have asked thousands of questions. 15 questions asked is somewhere around 98.5th percentile. That said, referring to the Q-ban as a "rate limit" seems... a bit euphemistic.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 1-per-6 months *is* rate limiting. Indeed, it is considered by most as a complete ban since one usually gets a dozen different assignments a week in school - but *technically* it is garden variety of rate-limiting.